# Display/block works only when div is inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div s that I want hide/show alternatively, my code works fine when I put those two div in a table but not when they are not in a table, but I don't want to put them in a table for some IE problems, here is my code

```
<div class="lazyLoad" id="more"><a href="javascript:openFromButton()"> <img id="yourid" src="../../images/view_more_arrow.png" border="0" height="6" width="11"></a> <a href="javascript:openFromButton()">view more</a></div></td>
  <div class="lazyLoad" id="load" style="display:none"><a> <img id="your" src="../../images/loader.gif" border="0" height="6" width="11"></a></a></div></td>

 function openFromButton(lastLoadedIndex) {
 lastLoadedIndex = (typeof(lastLoadedIndex)=='undefined') ? '' : lastLoadedIndex;

  document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'none';

jQuery.get('liste_ti.asp?from_item='+ lastLoadedIndex +'&param='+(new Date()).getTime(), function(data) { 
//alert(data);

jQuery("#list").append(data);
if(data) {
  document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'block';


}
else{
  document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'none';

}
 });

 }
```

Any help

Comment: In what way does the code fail to work? What happens, or what doesn't happen?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with your code?

Comment: nothing happens, the 'load' div should be displayed and the 'more ' div should have been hidden, but it's not what happens, that code is only appending data.

Comment: Does getting rid of those stray `</td>` tags help (I doubt it but they shouldn't be there).

Comment: yes they shouldn't be there, I got rid of them, thanks.
But the problem was due a td that wasn't closed, now solved ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a closing tag missed.